# Form to enable existing member to edit selected value in price set

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm, forms

I volunteer for a german NGO and we want to enable our members to easily update their yearly payment. We have the following:

1. A working installation of CiviCRM (v4.5.6)
2. A membership type we're interested in
3. A priceset assigned to this membership type
4. A custom field for the value of the selected price

I try to build the following:

> A simple form, which allows existing members to update their selected price (the custom field) from the given priceset. This requires a valid login, if there is no active session, a login screen should be displayed. The form will be embedded in an iFrame or similar.

I tried working with profiles and contribution pages but to no avail (as it is not setup as a recurring payment but rather a custom field). I found the Webform module and its CiviCRM integration but I'm not sure if that really is what I'm looking for.

Looking forward to any hints! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coding a custom solution (Drupal / CiviCRM API) because I ran into many issues with our specific setup.

But I also discovered and learned about [CiviCRM-Webform](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Webform+CiviCRM+Integration) and can recommend it for similar use cases.